# Confused about making a CSV file into a ZIP file in django

Tags: python, django, zip

I have a view that takes data from my site and then makes it into a zip compressed csv file. Here is my working code sans zip:

```
def backup_to_csv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=backup.csv'

    writer = csv.writer(response, dialect='excel')

    #code for writing csv file go here...

    return response
```

and it works great. Now I want that file to be compressed before it gets sent out. This is where I get stuck.

```
def backup_to_csv(request):

    output = StringIO.StringIO() ## temp output file
    writer = csv.writer(output, dialect='excel')

    #code for writing csv file go here...

    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=backup.csv.zip'

    z = zipfile.ZipFile(response,'w')   ## write zip to response
    z.writestr("filename.csv", output)  ## write csv file to zip

    return response
```

But thats not it and I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I got it. Here is my new function:

```
def backup_to_csv(request):

    output = StringIO.StringIO() ## temp output file
    writer = csv.writer(output, dialect='excel')

    #code for writing csv file go here...

    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=backup.csv.zip'

    z = zipfile.ZipFile(response,'w')   ## write zip to response
    z.writestr("filename.csv", output.getvalue())  ## write csv file to zip

    return response
```

Comment: Yep, that will work (if the uncompressed output fits nicely in memory,  else consider a temporary file on disk).

Answer (score 5):

Note how, in the working case, you `return response`... and in the NON-working case you return `z`, which is **NOT** an `HttpResponse` of course (while it should be!).

So: use your `csv_writer` NOT on `response` but on a temporary file; zip the temporary file; and write **THAT** zipped bytestream into the `response`!

Comment: Ok, I updated my OP to reflect what I think you're saying here. but there is still something I'm missing. I get an AttributeError saying "StringIO has no __len__ method". Should I be using something else other than StringIO for writing the csv to?

Comment: To extract the string value of a StringIO instance (so you can get its `len` etc etc), use `thestringioinstance.getvalue()` once you're done writing to it (and before you close it!-).

Answer (score 1):

```
zipfile.ZipFile(response,'w')
```

doesn't seem to work in python 2.7.9. The ***response*** is a **django.HttpResponse** object (which is said to be file-like) but it gives an error *"HttpResponse object does not have an attribute 'seek'*. When the same code is run in python 2.7.0 or 2.7.6 (I haven't tested it in other versions) it is OK... So you'd better test it with python 2.7.9 and see if you get the same behaviour.