# how to create csvs and write to zip file in Google App Engine (python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, zip

I'm trying to write multiple csvs to a zip file in Google App Engine. I found this post: [Confused about making a CSV file into a ZIP file in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403438/confused-about-making-a-csv-file-into-a-zip-file-in-django) which has been helpful. In fact, when I do:

```
o=StringIO.StringIO()
file = zipfile.ZipFile(file=o,compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,mode="w")
.. . ## add your csv files here
file.close()
o.seek(0)
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] ='application/zip'
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="your_csvs.zip"'
self.response.out.write(o.getvalue())
```

I get a blank zip file which is fine. However, above this, I have

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=sheet.csv'
writer = csv.writer(self.response.out)
writer.writerow(['Text Here'])
```

Which by itself lets me download a csv. Where I'm stuck is when I try to combine the two. If I do:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=sheet.csv'
writer = csv.writer(self.response.out)
writer.writerow(['Text Here'])

o=StringIO.StringIO()
file = zipfile.ZipFile(file=o,compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,mode="w")
file.writestr("sheet.csv", output.getvalue())
file.close()
o.seek(0)
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] ='application/zip'
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="your_csvs.zip"'
self.response.out.write(o.getvalue())
```

I get a zipfile that can't open. I'm fairly certain I'm using writestr incorrectly but I can't figure out the code to get the csv I create into the zip. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you saying you are writing *two* files out to the response? A CSV *and* a zipfile?

Comment: What is `output` here (from `output.getvalue()`, written to the `ZipFile()` object)?

Comment: hmm I guess writer = csv.writer(self.response.out) should have a different argument then, correct? I only want to write one file out to the response (a zipfile)

Comment: I'm not sure how to create the csv and "hold it" in memory to add it to the zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I am doing

```
        zh = StringIO()
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zh,'w')
        zi = zipfile.ZipInfo('test.csv')
        zi.compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
        zi.comment = 'Some comment'
        zf.writestr(zi, zh.getvalue())
        zf.close()
        payload = zh.getvalue()
```

Comment: makes sense; would payload then be what is returned (i.e. self.response.out.write(payload))?